# Linker error undefined reference to class::class (Person::Person in my case)

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am getting a linker error undefined reference to Person::Person when trying to implement my program. The three parts are below. I have been working on fixing it for a few hours now. I know it's probably something simple that I am just not seeing. But I have looked around on the internet and still have not found my answer. So any help would be appreciated.

```
#ifndef PERSON0_H_
#define PERSON0_H_

#include <string>

class Person // class declaration
{
private:
    static const int LIMIT = 25;
    std::string lname;
    char fname[LIMIT];
public:
   Person() {lname = ""; fname[0] = '\0';}
   Person(const std::string & ln, const char * fn = "Hay you");
   void Show() const;
   void FormalShow() const;
};

#endif

#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include "person0.h"


void Person::Show() const
{
 using namespace std;

      std::cout << fname << " " << lname << '\n';

}           

void Person::FormalShow() const
{
 using std::cout;

      std::cout << lname << ", " << fname << '\n';
}




#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "person0.h"

int main()
{
using namespace std;

Person one;
Person two("Smythecraft");
Person three("Dimwiddy", "Sam");
one.Show();
cout << endl;
one.FormalShow();
cout << endl;
two.Show();
cout << endl;
two.FormalShow();
cout << endl;
three.Show();
cout << endl;
three.FormalShow();        


cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not really a C++ person, so the terminology might be wrong, but I would say that the implementation of the

```
Person::Person(const std::string & ln, const char * fn)
```

constructor is missing.

Comment: As it turns out that dose not fix my problem. If I put in the constructor I get a previously defined error.

Comment: @user2205687: Can you show your implementation and the error message?